# Android app crashes when adding firebase crashlytics

Tags: android, firebase, okhttp, crashlytics

I'm migrating from fabric to firebase crashlytics. I've been able to migrate to AndroidX (which I believe was necessary). Then I followed [this](https://medium.com/@onkart10/migrating-from-fabric-to-firebase-crashlytics-e8819933c484) steps but the app crashes when I add the crashlytics dependency (everything works if I comment out the crashlytics implementation line).

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:17.0.0'
```

When using a physical phone, I don't get any error, just some SQLiteEventStore and JobInfoScheduler log and the sigkill:

https://gist.github.com/raquelhortab/60ebd50ead5aa820c34bc271a09e94b7

When using an emulator I get an okhttp3 error (you can see it in the gist above). Again, the only difference is the crashlytics line in the app's build.gradle.

The okhttp3 error made me think I might have to update glide and okhttp3 (which is not that easy) but it works just fine without crashlytics so I don't think that's the problem.

I've also tried the crashlytics version 17.2.2 and newer versions of firebase-related implementations, you can find the gradle files in the gist as well.

PS: I apologize if this has already been answered, searching crashes and crashlytics leads to many questions of crashes that are not realated to crashlytics (which is logic)

Comment: Hi, can you please add the error that you receive when your app crashes?

Comment: Hi! It's in the gist, can you see it there? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if this is firebase issue. can you try to add the same version for **com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor** and **com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp**. let's try **3.4.1**

Comment: It looks like it works!! God, I had tried so many version combinations... Thanks! If you post it as an answer I'll mark it as the solution

Comment: glad it workd. I added the answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It doesn't seem firebase issue from the error stack provide. Try to add the same version for `com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor` and `com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp`

try **3.4.1**